# Angular: Creating questions using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and to try to get a grasp of directives I'm trying to create one for the generation of a multiple-choice question. Here's what I want to get working:

```
<question type="multiple-choice"
          content="Hard tacos or soft tacos?"
          options="{{ [
            'Hard tacos!',
            'Soft tacos!',
            'Porque no los dos?'] }}"></question>
```

I don't think Angular will understand that I'm trying to pass an object for the `options` attribute of the question directive.

Here's what my directive is looking like so far:

```
app.directive("question", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      content: '@',
      options: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
      return "partials/question-" + attrs.type + ".html";
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my template (`question-multiple-choice.html`):

```
<h3 ng-bind="content"></h3>
<div ng-repeat="option in options()">
  <input type="radio" ng-value="option"> <span ng-bind="option"></span>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error though, and I don't know how to proceed:

```
Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 4 of the expression [{{ [
   'Hard tacos!',
   'Soft tacos!',
   'Porque no los dos?'] }}].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the interpolation `{{}}`, within your `options` attribute:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubLjys99/1/)**

```
<question type="multiple-choice"
          content="Hard tacos or soft tacos?"
          options="[
            'Hard tacos!',
            'Soft tacos!',
            'Porque no los dos?']"></question>
```

Furthermore, there is a typo in your `templateUrl` callback `attr.type` should be `attrs.type`

Update:
Since you want to have an an attribute as the model of your radio buttons, why not add an `ng-model` attribute itself using the `=` scope notation.

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubLjys99/2/)**

**question-multiple-choice.html**

```
    <h3 ng-bind="content"></h3>
    <div ng-repeat="option in options()">
      <input ng-model="$parent.ngModel" type="radio" ng-value="option" name="option"> <span ng-bind="option"></span>
    </div>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive("question", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      content: '@',
      options: '&',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
      return "question-" + attrs.type + ".html";
    }
  }
});
```

Note that I used `$parent.ngModel` in the template because the `ng-repeat` creates a child scope.

Comment: Ah okay, that worked just fine. Follow-up: I've added a new attribute, identifier. I want to set the value of this attribute to be my ng-model (via `ng-model="answers[identifier]"`) for my controller's scope object `answers`. Do I just need to transclude: true for this?

Comment: Ahhh wow I don't think I'd have ever thought of doing it so simply. Much appreciated. There's certainly a lot to wrap my head around with Angular!

Answer (score 0):

Use "=" instead of "&" (which is for passing functions) for the options attribute.

Then when you use the directive, remove the curly braces from the expression.

The "=" says you want to do two-way binding with the value, in this case an array.

Comment: The `options` attribute is an array of constants, two-way data binding isn't really suitable for this case.

Comment: @ryeballar maybe, but I'm pretty sure it will work. By the way neither is passing a function reference with &. I fail to see how your answer will solve the problem if the OP doesn't remove the &. With your comment in mind the OP could use @ and then do scope.eval() on the options attribute. But my way he could eventually pass an array object instead of an inline array.

Comment: @ryeballar ok guess I'm wrong :) Saw your demo, why does it work with & ?

Comment: As mentioned in the [**`$compile` documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile): `& or &attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. In reality it just uses the `$parse` service wherein it creates a wrapper of the actual context of the expression.

Comment: You can check the [**source code if you want to**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1949).

Comment: @ryeballar no need to check the source, I believed it when I saw the demo. Thanks for explaining, +1 coming up!